# Application to (deliberately) consume CPU time?

Tags: windows

Is there an application designed to consume a user defined amount of CPU time? For testing purposes?

For instance, it could be set to consume 57% of available CPU time to slow down some other application sufficiently, but not too much, in order to acquire a screenshot of a transient phenomenon.

For Unix systems there is [stress](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/), "workload generator for POSIX systems. It imposes a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O, and disk stress on the system.".

Platform: Windows.

Comment: If you wanted to take a slo-mo screenshot, you could just pull a frame out of a screencast using CamStudio or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a piece of software called [Battle Encoder Shirase](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) which is designed to do exactly this.

It functions not by consuming excess CPU time, but by rapidly suspending and resuming the target progress. It works much like a cheap dimmer switch. The result is much more consistent and predictable than something like `stress`, but in any case the results are pretty much the same.

Imagine 'voltage' means resumed at high, and suspended at low. If you set it to throttle the CPU of a particular process down to 25%, the process would run like so:

[image: pulse width modulation]

Comment: Yes, this (almost) work. Running "stress" in Cygwin with 1 process on a quad core system and limit set in Battle Encoder Shirase to 80% (20% left for the "stress" process) resulted in close to the expected CPU load of 25% x 0.2 = 3.75%. But "stress" is not suitable for this purpose as it starts a separate process for each CPU: There are only 3 targets in Battle Encoder Shirase and it can not limit for the 4th CPU on a quad core system. Battle Encoder Shirase remains the key to the solution, a program that uses 4 threads instead of 4 processes to load the CPUs is needed.

Comment: I bet there are dozens of `stress` replacements if you look around. For example here's one: http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/10/22/Max-CPU_3A00_-Another-one-for-your-developer-toolbox_2E002E002E00_.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The question seems difficult. I don't know of any tools which track CPU utilization and control their load according to it. I know that this was a problem for SETI@home project. They solved it by taking a time unit (can't remember if it was a second or a minute...) and have CPU loaded at 100% for one portion of it. So when user sets CPU load a 50%, half of the time unit  CPU would run  at 100% and other half at 0%. You can try with S@H and see if it will work for you. Link: http://setiathome.berkeley.edu

There is also [Mo'Slo](http://www.hpaa.com/moslo/), but I haven't used it since DOS days and I don't know how good it works under windows. It seems it works by making the target program use less CPU time, so it isn't what you need.

Answer (score 2):

CPU Burn tools usually focus on taking up all cycles.
Your requirement is interesting and I wonder if this can be done with a controlled version of the tool that will look its own CPU utilization and tune itself up or down to match a configured setting.

The classic form of the CPU burning tool is the [Mersenne Prime Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime95).
This is the place to get its [source](ftp://mersenne.org/gimps/) versions.

---

Rambling on ideas.
As an example of self tuning I recall writing a curve-plotting tool some time back that used an approximate curve plot with increasing accuracy (more iterations/recursion to get better curves). I converted it into a 'benchmark' of sorts by measuring the time taken to compute each iteration of the curve. I wanted to keep moving the curve (think screen savers) on the screen after drawing it with a sufficient accuracy. Based on the speed of the system under test, I tuned the movement (animation) to work at something like a 25 frame rate. So, faster systems showed better curves!

What you would do with the prime search code is to add in a CPU utilization 'sensor' and use it to slow down or increase the computation rate (to approximate configured CPU utilization).

<sup>This part of the answer would probably better suit on Stackoverflow `:-)`

Seeing you are active there too, maybe this would interest you.</sup>